# Ошибка записи: "text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified"

Tags: delphi, sql-server, sql

Delphi4 Sql 2008 varbinary max

В операторе Delphi4

```
TBlobField(qrySaveScan.FieldByName('No_Justification')).LoadFromFile(ScanPath);
```

при редактировании поля выдает ошибку

> text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы закидываете файл в нужное поле? И, что у этого поля тип text, ntext, или image?

Comment: varbinary(max)